# Objective C - design advice: Class to store a bodyweight value

Tags: objective-c, oop, object

As an aid to learning objective c/oop, I'm designing an iOS app to store periodic bodyweight measurements. I want to be able to retrieve the bodyweight in a variety of units (Kg, Lb, etc). For each bodyweight instance, can I/should I subclass NSNumber with a custom getter which return the weight in the correct unit? Perhaps I should simply subclass NSObject instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't not use `NSNumber` at all, do not even add a category to it - this class (cluster) if designed for when you need to store a primitive type as an object and little else.

It you wish to encapsulate a weight write a class to do it, something along the lines of (code typed at terminal):

```
@interface Weight : NSObject

@property double kilos:
@property double pounds;
// etc

@end

@implementation Weight
{
   double value; // stored in a suitable unit, kg, lb, oz, g, etc.
}

// implement getters and setters converting between unit of property and unit of value

// implement dependent property methods to setting, say, pounds produces a KVO
// notification for both pounds and kilos, etc. E.g.:

+ (NSSet *) keyPathsForValuesAffectingPounds
{
   return [NSSet setWithObject:@"kilos"];
}

@end
```

Now you can set the value as one unit, read it as another, and get KVO notifications for all properties whenever one is set.

You'll want to add constructors (e.g. `newWeightWithKilos:`), maybe operations (e.g. `addWeight:` - which can just add the internal values), and need to decide whether a `Weight` is mutable or immutable.

Answer (score 2):

> can I/should I subclass NSNumber with a custom getter which return the weight in the correct unit? Perhaps I should simply subclass NSObject instead?

Can you?  Yes.  Should you?  No.  NSNumber instances are actually never NSNumbers.  NSNumber acts as a dispenser for it's various subclasses, which means that when you subclass it, you are essentially promising to reimplement the class dispension aspect of NSNumber (the same is true of NSArray and NSString).

Try to write a category on NSNumber rather than attempt to subclass it, and even then, NSNumber was never designed for manipulation and mathematical operations.  Numbers are essentially immutable constructs, so you would be far better off writing a method that calculates things with primitives somewhere in your controller object.  In your particular situation, NSNumber would only really be appropriate for persistence.

Answer (score 0):

You need not sub class the NSNumber instead you can subclass NSObject and add a property to set the weight in base unit(eg: kg's) and then you can add several methods that take the weight in base unit and returns the converter value in the units you specify(lb etc).